# Blender to Three.js cube not showing

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

Hi guys im trying to export a cube from blender to three.js, I already exported the JSON but when I try to get the cube on code, it dont show up, I just get the `setColor` screen dunno why, I already tried a lof of things can't get it what am I doing wrong?

I paste here my code maybe some of you guys can help me to understand what I am doing wrong, he loads something as geometry I did a console log and get a JSON with vertices etc.. 
By the way the cube is the default cube on blender on point `0,0,0`.

**Three.js**

```
var renderer;
var scene;
var camera;

$(function () {

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xcccccc});

  var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
  loader.load('untitled.json', function (geometry) {
    console.log(geometry);
    geometry.computeMorphNormals();
    var mesaBilhar = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
    scene.add(mesaBilhar);
    });

 camera.position.x = -15;
 camera.position.y = 16;
 camera.position.z = 13;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
$("#WebGL-output").append(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
  // call the render function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed up adding Material to the Mesh.

```
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
  loader.load('untitled.json', function (geometry) {
    console.log(geometry);
    geometry.computeMorphNormals();
   var mesaBilhar = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,planeMaterial);
    scene.add(mesaBilhar);
    });
```